# Access a generic array via type properties

Tags: typescript

I have a file to parse and would like to define a type for its header and cast the beginning of data to that type for easier use in code instead of using indexes. Simplified example would be something along the lines:

```
type T = {
  id: string,
  value: number
}

let data = ['demoID', 123, ...];
let id = ((data as any) as T).id;
// error occurs as .id is not 0th index
```

How can I make my idea happen in Typescript?

Comment: TypeScript cannot change runtime behavior; it cannot turn `.id` into `[0]`.  Instead, parse the array into a class.

Comment: @SLaks can you elaborate more? My TS experience is fairly new

Comment: Code typo at the last line - can't edit it (too short), but a parenthesis is missing

Comment: @SLaks Why would you use a class just to store data? JavaScript has plain objects already

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is:

```
'id' must have the type of T.id
```

which makes sense (orally). However, this is not the way to do in TypeScript. *the type of T.id* is `string`, so you should do

```
let id = data[0] as string;
```

Which will allow you to write, further down your code, something like this:

```
let t: T = {
    id: id, // no need to cast :)
    value: 10
}
```

Comment: Using an index is exactly what I try to get rid of. I would like to just "cast" the data to a type and use property name instead of an index :)

Answer (score -2):

you are trying to switch from positional to associative/named structure. Why not add constructor or factory function to the type T that looks like this:

```
constructor(id, value, ...rest){

this.id = id;
this.value = value;
// etc
}
```

Comment: btw "generic" is not the correct term here. "mixed" is more appropriate